Abresch's paper on smoothing Riemannian metrics
I have came into this paper cited by lots of people (including lots of famous work, like Cheeger-Fukaya-Gromov's paper on $\mathcal N$-structures) written by Uwe Abresch:
Uber das Glatten Riemannscher Metriken, Habilitationsshrift, Rheinischen Friedrich-Wilhelms-Universitat Bonn (1988).
But I never found this paper. A somehow "precise statement" I can find is the following one from Chopping Riemannian Manifolds by Cheeger-Gromov:
Theorem.
On the set of complete Riemannian manifolds, $(M^n,g)$, with $|K|\leq1$, there exists for all $\epsilon>0$, a smoothing operator $g\to S_\epsilon(g)=\tilde g$ such that:
\begin{gather}
(1+\epsilon^2)^{-1}g\leq\tilde g\leq (1+\epsilon^2)g\\
\|\nabla_VW-\tilde\nabla_VW\|\leq C(n,\epsilon)\|V\|\|W\|\\
\|\tilde\nabla^k \tilde R\|\leq C(n,R,\epsilon)
\end{gather}
Moreover, the value of $\tilde g$ at $p\in M^n$ only depends on $B_{1/4}(p)$.
Question 1: The theorem seems to be local. I am wondering if we a prior have $g$ is nearly flat (say on a ball), e.g. the curvature $R$ is very small, then with the above process, can we still smooth it to $\tilde g$ that is also nearly flat?
Question 2: I believe the answer to the above question is yes if one can go over Abresch's paper. There are also smoothing technique based on Ricci flows but seems to be non-local. I was also aware of the paper Controlled Geometry via Smoothing by Petersen-Wei-Ye where Abresch's idea is sketched. But with that I still am not able to recover Abresch's proof. I am wondering is there anyone who has ever read Abresch's original paper?
